# How to call a function with multiple in\out params not knowing their order using Reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, reference, out

I have a type instance `t`:

- with a function of whose signature I know only general structure like this `public void  Action(T1in ps, ..., TNin ps, out T1out,..., out TKout)`

and two Dictionaries `In` and `Out`

- with pairs of `{Type, instance}` inside.

I assume that there are no other arguments required in order to call an `Action` of `t`.

So how to call a function with multiple inputs and outputs using Reflection/[Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#really-late-binding-arguments-with-refout-arguments-etc) knowing their types yet not their order?

Comment: I assume that the signature will never have a duplicate type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reflection: How to Invoke Method with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: the signature will never have a duplicate type

Comment: @viveknuna: the params ordering is the main issue for me so no it does not

Comment: So the dictionary would only contain the **input** parameters, correct?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: How to gather output parameters then?

Comment: @viveknuna I would say that doesn't cover it as OP is also trying to distinguish A. the proper order dynamically and B. `out` parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke a method via reflection, you pass an `object[]` containing all of the parameters. For `out` parameters, you leave the corresponding value in the array as `null`. Once the method has completed you can retrieve the value from the corresponding position in the array.

To demonstrate this, let's assume the following two classes:

```
public class A
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => "[B] Id=" + Id; // for Console.WriteLine
}
```

We are going to invoke the following static method which includes three input parameters and one `out` parameter (of type `B`):

```
public static void MyMethod(int i, string x, A a, out B b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In Method - i={0}", i);
    Console.WriteLine("In Method - x={0}", x);
    Console.WriteLine("In Method - A.Something={0}", a.Something);

    b = new B { Id = 33 };
}
```

To invoke the method with the appropriate arguments we will loop over the array returned by `GetParameters` and populate our `object[]`.

To determine if our parameter is an `out` parameter we must look at two things: `ParameterInfo.IsOut` and `ParameterInfo.ParameterType.IsByRef`*. If both values are `true` we will simply leave a space in the array. Otherwise we will use the `ParameterType` property to query the dictionary for the appropriate instance (throwing an exception if we don't have an instance):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Type, object>
{
    [typeof(int)] = 5,
    [typeof(string)] = "Hello",
    [typeof(A)] = new A { Something = "World" }
};

MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(MyMethod));

// get the parameters and create the input array
var @params = method.GetParameters();
var methodArgs = new object[@params.Length];
// loop over the parameters
// see below for LINQ'ified version
for (var i = 0; i < @params.Length; i++)
{
    var p = @params[i];
    // if it's an output parameter, ignore its value
    if (p.IsOut && p.ParameterType.IsByRef)
        continue;
    // get the value based on the parameter type or throw if not found
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(p.ParameterType, out var arg))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot find parameter of type " + p.ParameterType.Name);

    methodArgs[i] = arg;
}
```

Finally we will invoke the method using the arguments array we have created. Once the method completes, we can access the output parameter via the appropriate value in the array

```
// Note: if Method is NOT a static method, we need to pass the instance as
// the first parameter. This demo uses a static method so we pass null
method.Invoke(null, methodArgs);
Console.WriteLine("In Main - B={0}", methodArgs[3]);
```

Running the above will print the following:

> In Method - i=5
>
> In Method - x=Hello
>
> In Method - A.Something=World
>
> In Main - B=[B] Id=33

You can "shorten" the loop to the following:

```
var methodArgs2 = method.GetParameters()
    .Select(param =>
        param.IsOut && param.ParameterType.IsByRef ? null :
        dict.TryGetValue(param.ParameterType, out var pValue) ? pValue :
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Parameter of type {param.ParameterType.Name} was not found"))
    .ToArray();
```

If you are *absolutely certain* that your dictionary will contain all of the appropriate types, we can make it simpler:

```
var methodArgs = method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.IsOut && p.ParameterType.IsByRef ? null : dict[p.ParameterType]).ToArray();
```

**Note**: if you statically know the type you can cast it back from `object`.

```
B b = (B)methodArgs[3];
```

Unfortunately you will not be able to do this with the `Type` object alone. If you don't know the type you could switch using pattern matching or `is`/`as`

**Note**: you could also get the parameter's zero-based index (something you mention above) using the [`ParameterInfo.Position`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.parameterinfo.position?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_ParameterInfo_Position) property:

```
var index = p.Position;
methodArgs[index] = ... ;
```

* Testing *only* `ParameterInfo.IsOut` is not sufficient. Compilers may insert the `OutAttribute` in other cases (such as COM). An `out` parameter will have both this attribute (which is what sets `IsOut`) and will also have a by-ref type `T&`. Similarly, `ref` parameters will have the `IsByRef` flag, but they will *not* have `IsOut`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38110036/491907) for more details.

Now, if you had `ref` parameters you'd have to do things a bit differently. First of all `ref` typically assumes that a value exists as a pre-condition, but VB doesn't necessarily require it (where `out` does not exist). To check for parameters of this type you'd first have to check `!p.IsOut && p.ParameterType.IsByRef`. Then, to get the instance from your dictionary you'll need to turn the ByRef type (`T&`) into a normal one (`T`) using `GetElementType`:

```
if (!dict.TryGetValue(p.ParameterType.GetElementType(), out var pValue)) {
   // if you know it's safe to pass null, then continue 
   // otherwise you may need to create a new object using Activator
}
```